# Sum of numbers using for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop

**Is there something like this in python?**

`sum += i for i in range(10)`

*sum should be 55*

Comment: `total = sum(range(11))` using the built-in function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Comment: @khelwood He said he has to use a `for` loop.

Comment: Could you give a little more detail on what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no one-liner for it, like there are for list comprehensions

```
total = 0
for i in range(10):
    total += i
```

Don't use `sum` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function (which happens to do what your loop does).